# Flutter Windows. Multiple versions of the same app don't have specific local data (Shared Preferences)

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I have developed an application in Flutter Windows.

There is an issue where if you have two instances of the same app in separate folders, it still seems to store the Shared Preferences in a common place for both apps.

For instance, folder 1 is "settings local", folder 2 is "settings server", with copies of the compiled release in each. You would expect that each instance would have it's own private storage of data, not shared between multiple instances.

Is there any way to get the app to store local data like Shared Preferences (I also used Encrypted Shared Preferences) in the folder containing each instance, or at least a unique location?